# How to make nested ifelse loop dynamic

Tags: r, for-loop, if-statement

i Have a Df:abc as below

```
Sr|VALUE
a |85
b |120
c |145
d |225
e |100
f |325
g |410
```

I am writing below code to create a count for each record such that its 0 for VALUE<100,1 for VALUE between[100,200),2 for VALUE>=200

```
Stepdif<-100

abc = within(abc, {                   
  Count = ifelse(abc$VALUE>=Stepdif & abc$VALUE<2*Stepdif,1,ifelse(abc$VALUE>=2*Stepdif ,2,0))
  })
```

to give result as

```
Sr|VALUE|Count
a |85   |0
b |120  |1
c |145  |1
d |225  |2
e |100  |1
f |325  |2
g |410  |2
```

Now i want a code using which i can define count for each duration of 100. I dont want to write code as such

```
Count = ifelse(abc$VALUE>=Stepdif & abc$VALUE<2*Stepdif,1,ifelse(abc$VALUE>=2*Stepdif & abc$VALUE<3*Stepdif,2,ifelse(abc$VALUE>=3*Stepdif & abc$VALUE<4**Stepdif,3,ifelse(abc$VALUE>=4*Stepdif ,4,0))))
```

Rather i want to make it dynamic so that if i change the no of iteration from 4 to 6 , i dont have to rewrite the code again.

```
expected result
Sr|VALUE|Count
a |85   |0
b |120  |1
c |145  |1
d |225  |2
e |100  |1
f |325  |3
g |410  |4
```

Comment: How about using `cut` i.e. `with(abc, cut(VALUE, breaks = c(-Inf, Stepdif *(1:2), Inf)))`

Comment: Look into `findInterval()` in the `base` package.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

hope this will be of help:

```
   funfun=function(x,n){n=1:n*100; findInterval(x,n)}

  funfun(k$VALUE,2)
  [1] 0 1 1 2 1 2 2
  funfun(k$VALUE,4)
  [1] 0 1 1 2 1 3 4
```